# For each integer $k$ such that $s \leq k \leq t$, show that there exist a $5-regular$ graph $G_k$ such that $\chi(G_k)=k$

Tags: graph-theory

Among all $5-regular$ graphs, let $s$ be the smallest chromatic number, and $t$ be the largest chromatic number . For each integer $k$ such that $s \leq k \leq t$, show that there exist a $5-regular$ graph $G_k$ such that $\chi(G_k)=k$

For this problem, the book say $s=2$ and $t=6$. It's easy to see that

$$\chi(G_k) \leq 1+ \Delta(G)$$$

Since this is a $5-regular$, $\Delta(G)=5$, so $\chi(G_k)=k\leq 6$. However, I can't see why $s=2$.

I know that $\chi(G) \geq \omega(G)$ for every graph $G$, but there nothing guarantee that the largest complete subgraph of $G$ has order $2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $s$ is the smallest possible chromatic number for a 5-regular graph.

No (nonempty) graph can have chromatic number $1$ (with at least one edge, its two ends must have different colors).

So all we need to show is that there *is* some 5-regular graph with chromatic number 2. But that is easy enough -- the complete bipartite graph $K_{5,5}$ will do.

(Note that strictly speaking, before you know that $t=6$, you need to show that there *is* a graph with chromatic number 6. But $K_6$ will do for that.)

Comment: so I can't just use the theorem to get $t=6$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Which theorem? $\chi(G)\le 1+\Delta(G)$ in itself will only tell you $t\le 6$.

Comment: oh, so I need to say $\chi(K_6)=6$ to confirm that $t=6$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Yup.

Comment: I always got hard time trying to understand these theorem correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: The title question also asks to find 5-regular graphs with chromatic numbers 3, 4 and 5. Did you find those yourself?

Comment: because they say there exist, so for each chromatic number, I only need one graph, right? I got $\chi(K_{2,2,2})=3$, I'm working on the other two

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Right in principle, but $K_{2,2,2}$ is not 5-regular!

Comment: oh, my bad, it's 4-regular, then I have to try that one again. Thanks